# Windows SDK for COCOA API

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm just starting off with IOS app dev. I was just curious to know if there are any sdk's in windows available to simulate the cocoa API.
In simple words can i program, compile and execute an Objective-C code on windows OS through any simulators, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question was about running Cocoa apps on Windows, not developing iOS apps under Windows.  There are a few projects that are attempting to implement the Cocoa APIs under windows, but I'm not sure how successful they are being.  There is one at http://www.cocotron.org/ which looks promising.

Comment: Exactly my question. I just wanted to know if i can compile an objective-C code on windows. I searched in through some stuff and what i came across is that i can do that using a CygWin or MinGW compiler. There seem to be a few issues with that though.

Comment: I really appreciate your answering the question. It was great help to me. As i'm sort of new in IOS app dev, i'm gonna be having a lot of questions pinging in my head ;). Ur help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only real way to do iOS development is in a genuine Mac environment.

Comment: that isn't unafortunately :), by the way only a mac (Mac OS) works for iOS/Mac OSX development.

Comment: I agree, but my question was if i can just compile the Objective-C code on some other platform apart from MAC OS.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question though, i should have been more specific about my question. i'll be careful from next time onwards :).